# Creepage distance in a solid state relay

Tags: solid-state-relay, creepage

My circuit has a driver TRIAC optocoupler and a TRIAC.
I want to replace this combination with a solid state relay.

The TRIAC optocoupler datasheet explicitly specifies the creepage distance (distance between the light emitting side pin and the light receiving side pin, along the package surface.)

When I check datasheets of solid state relays I don't find the creepage distance parameter.

For my design it is important to have a creepage distance of at least 6 mm to meet the standards.

Is there any way I can calculate or estimate the creepage distance for the solid state relay?

Answer (score 2):

Creepage is a property of both your PCB and the package, with the shortest distance of the two limiting it. Creepage is always measured along a surface connecting the two pins. The point of a creepage specification being that the surface can become contaminated with dust, atmospheric pollution, moisture, fingerprints etc, so can fail over a longer distance than the internal isolation of the component. You can improve your PCB distance by routing slots, you can't improve the package.

If you need to meet standards, and your intended component doesn't specify a creepage distance, don't use it. Find a component that **is** specified to meet your standards.

All components specify footprint dimensions in their datasheet. However, leads may emerge from the package sides, or the bottom, and be sleeved or not with additional encapsulant, or the package could be slotted, meaning that creepage distance may be larger or smaller than can be inferred from the footprint. Unless the creepage is actually specified, the component cannot be trusted to maintain that distance if they change the packaging (when moving manufacrturing to a different line, or reducing cost) whilst maintaining the same part number and data sheet.

Comment: I see many optocoupler  datasheets are specifiying the creepage distance. a solid state relay datasheet doesnot specify anything about creepage distance is there a reason for it

Comment: … as already said in both Neil's and Dave's answer, spani. That *is* defined in the datasheet, as dimensions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller a spec of package dimensions and lead configuration might do it, but they are all changable while being able to keep the same footprint. As ever, if there isn't a spec, don't use - especially for safety or regulation critical parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Creepage is a property of your PCB, not of the SSR itself. The creepage distance is the distance between the edges of the pads you create for for the SSR pins. Obviously, this depends on the pin spacing, which **is** in the datasheet, but there's still room for you to play with pad size and shape, as well as add features like grooves or slots to your PCB design.

Comment: I understand that creepage distance comes into play while designing the footprints. When I say creepage distance I am more concerned about the distance between input LED and the triac.

Comment: There is no "creepage" there. Creepage is current leaking through surface contamination, and inside the package of the SSR, there is no opportunity for that kind of contamination. The relevant datasheet parameter for that is "isolation voltage".

Comment: OK. Say I am using MOC3061 optocoupler triac in my design. Datasheet specification: safety and insulation ratings: the creepage distance is mentioned. >7mm. so you mean to say this is the property related to PCB footprint and not distance between input LED and the triac

Comment: just to repeat what you've been told three times now: yes.

Answer (score 0):

In the [MOC3061 data sheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2277613.pdf) I see this: -

[image]

This is the external creepage outside of the device. Your PCB creepage will degrade this slightly in most cases.

> *Is there any way I can calculate or estimate the creepage distance for
> the solid state relay?*

Look at the data sheet and examine the package dimensions.